# Cannot extend across 2 monitors in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, hp, multiple-monitors

I have xubuntu on an HP DL360 G7 server.
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Machine has two vga ports, one at the back and one at the front.

I can get an identical desktop displayed on both monitors, but cannot get the desktop extended across the two.

I've tried switching off 'Mirror displays' in the display application and arranging the two side by side. Doesn't work however. 'Identify displays' shows them both as Display 2, no matter how I arrange them.

xrandr gives:

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA-0 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02
   1280x960      60.00
   1152x864      75.00    69.97
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
   832x624       74.55
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94
   720x400       70.08
VGA-1 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02
   1280x960      60.00
   1152x864      75.00    69.97
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
   832x624       74.55
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94
   720x400       70.08

Is it possible to use two monitors on this machine in any way other than both showing identical output?

Although I have 2 two physical monitors attached to this machine and the Display application lets me see 2 monitors and drag one to the side of the other, the HardInfo application informs that I only have a single monitor.

On my laptop, also running xubuntu with a second monitor, where the desktop does extend across the 2nd monitor, HardInfo reports that I have 2 monitors.

It occurs to me that maybe in a DL360, although there are 2 physical vga ports, the wires both connect to the same thing internally.

As suggested by Stormlord below, I've tried:

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --primary --left-of VGA-1
```

but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Apologies. I mis-typed my ubuntu version number. Now corrected.

Comment: Normally you change the way 2nd monitor behave in Settings->Devices->Displays Choose a Display Mode that you want, Joint, Mirror or Single.

Comment: Thanks Bernard, I've added a bit more detail to my post.

Comment: So you can see two displays in the arrangement but identity shows that both displays are idenfied as display 2? That is a very strange problem. Since it only shows the arrangement for Join Display whenit can see detect two display devices. And yet things are not working.

Comment: "So you can see two displays in the arrangement but identity shows that both displays are idenfied as display 2?"  Yes, that's the situatiion.

Comment: Can you capture the dmesg output from the time when you have no monitor connected, to one monitor then two monitors. Curious to see the display driver messages.

Comment: Bernard: I disconnected both monitors & booted the machine. I then ssh'd to it & ran journalctl -f. Connecting & disconnecting the monitors, in any order produces no output. Please correct me if that's not the test you suggested I perform.

Comment: After you plug-in the monitors, you need to enable them in Ubuntu before you will see any messages I think.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and try this command to have `xrandr` make the change:

`xrandr --output VGA-0 --primary --left-of VGA-1`

If `xrandr` succeeds, you have to run this command every time you log in to your user account though.